# JavaScript extern class or array visible into onmessage worker

Tags: javascript, class, external, worker

With p5.js in a first time I cannot draw gradually the Koch snowflake: when a click to perform I see the result of the drawing when the recursion is gone.

so I implemented it with worker thread

As I don't know how to share external var like a class or an array (because if a create a type="module" script it is not ok with the worker.js)

I can arrived to do it with difficulty

'Koch snowflake' is made in recursive mode.

The project is

- index.html
- main.js
- worker.js that contain
  (onmessage = function... , and the VonKoch class)

in worker.js it's like

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Worker: Message received from main script');
  let depth = e.data.depth;
  let f = new VonKoch(VonKoch);
};

class VonKoch {

  constructor(depth) {
     ...
  }
  pencil_advance(){
    ...
    postMessage([this.x, this.y, this.x + dx, this.y + dy, ]);
```

Surprising ! it can send message from/into the class which is out of onmessage

```
 }
 ...
}
```

From the main.js it is like:

```
function setup() {

  noLoop();

  createCanvas(800, 400);
  if (window.Worker) {
    const myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
    let el = {profondeur:profondeur};
    myWorker.postMessage(el);
    let a=0;
```

a message has been received so with p5.js it draws a line

```
    myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
      line(e.data[0],e.data[1],e.data[2],e.data[3]);
      a++;
    };
```

With that I can see the draws gradually.

---

Ok, but I want more simple and speed result with an external array[][] of pixel that I can redraw every setInterval( ...; redraw(), 500).

The "main.js" can recognize this array if it is declared and initialized in "worker.js" but when this array is modified in "worker.js" (with VonKoch class), the main.js will see the initial array class without modification. Maybe it is come from "new Worker("worker.js")?

And if I create this array class in the "main.js" it won't be recognized in "worker.js".

The only way to have a "array class" that is recognized in "main.js" is to put it in the "worker.js".

Thank you for your help

Comment: And what happens if you put it in localstorage ?

Comment: `localStorage.colorSetting = '#a4509b'`.    in an external file will not be visible in "worker.js"   whith this attempt  `if (!localStorage.getItem('colorSetting')) {
  console.log("no");
} else {
  console.log("yes");`
}

Comment: localStorage is not accessible in the "worker.js"

Comment: You are rigth but IndexedDB seem accessible https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker

Comment: I have tried with indexedDB. After creating DB i use it in "worker.js" how open DB and draws in the matrix from DB. Every 1/2 sec in the "main.js"  i open the DB to draw the matrix points. It is taking a lot of time lot lot. With a recursion of 2 it's frozen. Normaly i get good result with recursion of 8 (max).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

With localStorage : not ok (see comment)
with indexedDB : not ok (see comment)

The solution is : 
in the "worker.js" that perform  Koch snowflake, when it does to draw there is a test of time. If the Date.now() is greater than 500 (ms) i send the matrix with post.
So the "main.js" while draw the matrix with p5.js after receiving the message comes from "worker.js".
It is fast

[depth of 12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8R8ERoq1YWM)